# Duplicate device input events on unix (/dev/input/event)

Tags: python, linux, events, driver, device

I'm using linux/ubuntu, and I would like to play a little bit with my touchpad. I'm trying to use python-evdev to read events from /dev/input/events, for now just printing them:

```
import evdev
dev = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event6')

import time
while True:
  try:
    for event in dev.read():
      print event
  except:
    print " ~ "
    time.sleep(.5)
```

If I do run that script in with root privilege in a virtual console (outside X, pressing ctrl+alt+F1), the script does print events when I touch the touchpad. Yet, if X is on screen and I run this in a gnome-terminal console, nothing is printed; I somehow guess this is normal, the inputs are intercepted by X. Yet I would like to get them anyway. Is there a way to duplicate whatever comes from /dev/input/event6 so thqt both X and my script can read all events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, a bit late on the answer here.

Up until version 1.8, the xorg synaptics driver used the EVIOCGRAB ioctl to prevent events to be delivered to other clients. That's disabled now by default, you can still use the GrabEventDevice option to disable it on your machine for older versions (see man synaptics).

In short, nothing wrong with your script, it's the synaptics driver that's the problem here. You'll find that your script will work on other devices just fine (though the xorg wacom driver did also grab the device until recently).

upstream commit in synaptics:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-synaptics/commit/?id=f1948e08ee9894864254a18098e4f4fceb6e322f

Answer (score -1):

So, your idea is, X got the data from your touchpad, so that your python code is blocked from receiving touchpad signal, right? Or, may I repeat your words as: at least for some specific kind of device, an application can't get /dev/input/event*, when another is reading from that device?

Theoritically, since linux make all devices as a file, you are accessing a file as read-only, while X is also read-only accessing the file.

I just did another experiment as: I have a infrared reciver on my archlinux, and I connected to the system in two ssh consoles. I use two ways to access IR, that is, two applications to read the file of /dev/input/event0 (event0 is the SF on my arch):

1, a piece of python code, with evdev;

2, a shell command as: sudo cat /dev/input/event0 | hexdump

You can look on the 2nd as working as your X. If you were reasoning correctly, they both should not receive data from the IR (event0) on the same time, when I sending signal from a IR remote controller, right? But, I really got date on the two ssh consoles(I wish I could post image, but I am new with too low reputation to do so).

So, I think it should not be the reason. I guess it might be because of your touchpad itself. You know, some devices can only work on a single application. e.g., keyboard can only enter characters on the active application, and some input method just make itself as active over other applications, and redirect after it processed. Also, say, if you had a VM running on your system, and you use only one mouse, what would happen if you are moving pointer on the host desktop? Will the pointer in VM move? Or vice versa?

So I need more info about your touchpad. If your TP works only with a single active applicatio, I am afraid you need somethink like a hook to get touchpad signal ahead of X, and redirec it to X and your python code, which might be beyond evdev.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a kernel input handler based on evdev so that the device input is distributed both to the normal /dev/input/eventN and, let's say, /dev/input/copied_eventN

X would read from /dev/input/eventN but you would still be able to read from /dev/input/copied_eventN

Actually you could very easily create a kernel module by copy-pasting the code in drivers/input/evdev.c